# Interrupt running code

Tags: jquery

For example; 
They are my links,     HomePage - Users

When I click homepage load js code. How I can interrupt when click Users this running code and start again.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your individual Javascript functions should only be running for split seconds. There should be no single long-running function that you need to actually *interrupt*. If there is, you need to design it so it is *interruptable*. Like:

```
function foo() {
    while (/* something */) {
        if (stopFlag) {
            return;
        }

        // do something
    }
}
```

When you want to interrupt the function, you set the global `stopFlag` to `true` and the function will exit soonish. That's rarely a necessary design pattern in the browser though (and only possible to a limited extend in the first place due to the single-threadedness of JS).

The best answer I can give to this vague and broad question of yours: design your Javascript in a way that you don't have this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element_class').click( function(event){
// your code here
event.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$('.element_class').click( function(event){
// your code here
return false;
});
```